# what to use parse xml file in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, xml-parsing, xmltype

I need to load and parse this huge xml file in Oracle 11g. will be having a structure something like this :

```
<condition>
   <if test='check'>
       <name>abc</name>
   </if>
   <else>
        <name>efg</name>
   </else>
</condition>
```

Based on applied 'check', I need to create objects.

Earlier I was doing this parsing in python using lxml. Even before that, I used to use dom based parser in python, but its performance was pretty bad.

Also, I need to validate this file before parsing, using a DTD file.

So, whats the best option to use while switching to oracle. Or maybe in Java. I can use that thru java stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [XML Parser for PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96621/adx20ppl.htm) if you're using 9i or later. DTD validation is supported.